# Firebase Auth OnAuthStateChanged(): how and where to implement?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After applying security rules to my Firebase backend, I am running into the issue of my services in the app attempting to use Firebase before the current user has been resolved. I'd like some assistance with how and where to implement onAuthStateChanged() at the top level. This is the error I'm getting:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

I've seen this question asked plenty of times here but I can't get a specific answer that would be tailored towards my app.

This is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  title = 'angular';
}
```

My app.component.html file:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    
    <span class="spacer"></span>

    <!-- Account menu -->
    <ng-container>
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="account"><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon></button>
      <mat-menu #account="matMenu">
        <ng-container *ngIf="authService.userData as user">
          <div class="display-name">{{(user.displayName) ? user.displayName : 'User'}}</div>
          <div class="email">{{user.email}}</div>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button class="no-focus" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button class="no-focus" mat-menu-item><a (click)="authService.SignOut()">Sign Out</a></button>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>

  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav [opened]="opened">
    <mat-nav-list>
       ...
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And my auth.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../models/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any;

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {    
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

  ...

  // Sign out 
  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
    })
  }

}
```

Here's what is implementing the auth service and using Firebase:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, DocumentData, DocumentReference, QuerySnapshot } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private authService: AuthService) { }

  /*
  ----------------------------------------------------
                  Transactions
  ---------------------------------------------------- 
  */

  GetTransactions(intvl: Interval): Observable<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>> {
    return this.firestore.collection('transactions', ref => ref
      .orderBy('date', 'asc')
      .where("userId", "==", this.authService.userData.uid))
      .get();
  }
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing the equivalent in AngularFire by implementing `this.afAuth.authState.subscribe`?  Also, I don't see the code that's generating the error you cite here.  Perhaps you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: For reference, I added to the post what is calling Firebase and what's erroring out.

Comment: I believe your code is suppose to subscribe to authState in order to get the user object whenever it first becomes available.  It looks like your use of `this.authService.userData` is not be waiting for the first user object to be emitted.

Comment: Fixed it. I implemented onAuthStateChanged() in the AuthGuard. Works like a charm.